# Simplest way to to write parallel C/C++ modules to be used in Python

Tags: python, c++, multithreading, scikit-learn

#### Short background (not really necessary)

I've been working on writing an alternative ( *less-resources demanding* ?) [mean shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_shift) C++ module to the [Scikit-Learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.MeanShift.html) one.

I've been using, on the C++ side, the [nanoflann](https://github.com/jlblancoc/nanoflann) library for building and searching the KD-Trees.

Basically I have two numpy arrays that i pass to my C++ MeanShift function via Cython, which then returns the list of cluster centers found.

It turns out to be a little faster, circa 7 times (I'm still actively working on it).

#### My question :

I'd like to parallelize the most expensive portions of my C++ code, like the for loops used for the convergence, but, since this C++ module will be imported into python I'd like to be doing so in the most secure & simple way.

I thought about using OpenMP, do you have any suggestion?

Thank you!
Have a nice day.

#### Edit / Code snippet

Thank you @bivouac0, i am now able to compile the whole.

Now I'm struggling against the logical / technical side. 
Let me write you a snippet of the code I want to parallelize.

I have a `std::vector<std::pair<size_t, double> > > matches` vector and a fairly large `double samples[N]` array.
I want to use the first element of the pairs stored in the `matches` vector to calculate the access index to the larger `samples` array (see code beneath):
This is the method that does it:

```
typedef std::vector<std::pair<size_t, double> > searchResultPair; 
double* calcMean(size_t nMatches, searchResultPair matches,
    double* samples) {
/*
*/
double* returnArray = new double[3];
returnArray[0] = 0;
returnArray[1] = 0;
returnArray[2] = 0;
double x = y = z = 0;
for (size_t i = 0; i < nMatches; i = i + 1) {
    x = x + samples[3 * (matches[i].first)];
    y = y + samples[3 * (matches[i].first) + 1];
    z = z + samples[3 * (matches[i].first) + 2];
     }
returnArray[0] = x/nMatches;
returnArray[1] = y/nMatches;
returnArray[2] = z/nMatches;

return(returnArray);
}
```

Is there a way to concurrently access the `matches[i].first` variable?

I've tried with `#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:x,y,z) num_threads(n_threads)` but it downgrades the performance (1 thread > 2 threads > 4 threads > 8 threads and so on...).

Does my question have any sense? Am I mistaken anywhere? 
It might just be an overhead to manage a parallel `n_threads` team to calculate the partial sums `x,y,z`, since the elements in a `vector` are stored contigously...

I could split the above for-loop in 3 parts and try to parallelize every one of them. *Could it be a good idea?*
That calculation over there is nested inside a `while` nested in another for loop, and it's the most important method of the whole module.

Comment: OMP is pretty easy. I tend to use it in a wrapper for parallel for loops for the most part which give them a functional-style interface similar to TBB like: `pfor(start_index, end_index, chunk_size, func);` and `pfor_each(c.begin(), c.end(), chunk_size, func);` Also makes it easy to swap between different parallel libs to compare their performance characteristics.

Comment: I've used OMP in c++ code that is imported into python without issue.  All the OMP instructions hide behind the c++ function calls so the fact that you're importing them into python is somewhat irrelevant. You just need to be sure to apply the correct c++ compiler directives to enable OMP when you build your module.

Comment: @bivouac0 I've tried with OMP, but got and ImportError python-side (`undefined symbol: GOMP_parallel`). 
I've added the -fopenmp flag, but I might be mistaking other compiling options (even the compiler itself!). 
Any suggestion?

Comment: Without the actual data it's difficult for someone else to help find an answer, however I'd first try to use `omp parallel for` on a single loop to see if it will speed up an accumulate.  I'd then look at the `omp sections` to parallelize the different for loops.  You should be able to get a decent speed-up but it sometimes takes a little experimenting to get the right combo.  Try to write your code as compact as possible.  Sometimes that helps OMP compile a fast solution.  If you want more help than this, you'll probably need to post a slice of the project with code and data ready to run.

Comment: Hey @bivouac0, thank you for the answer. 
I've also asked on CodeReview, here's the [full code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/185042/parallelize-a-for-loop-that-sums-up-different-elements-from-an-array)

Comment: I tried a couple of things on your code but wasn't able to get a speed-up.  I'm thinking that gcc is already compiling with the simd instructions (similar to `omp simd`) so adding a `omp parallel for` isn't going to help.  Note:  you're allocating a double* inside of your function but I don't see a delete so you're creating a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

In reference to the above issues with compiling the c++ code with OpenMP, you probably just need to include the `gomp` library.  Here's a simple setup.py script that works for me...

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize, build_ext
# run as... python setup.py build_ext

ext = Extension("entity_lookup",    # name of extension
    ["src/entity_lookup.pyx", "src/EntityLookupImpl.cpp", "src/IndexDictImpl.cpp"],
    language="c++",     # this causes Pyrex/Cython to create C++ source
    #include_dirs=[...],                       
    libraries=['gomp'], # or include explicity with extra_link_args below                         
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
    #extra_link_args=['/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1'], # see above
    extra_compile_args=['-fopenmp', '-std=c++11']
)

setup(
    name = 'EntityLookup',
    version = 0.4,
    description = 'Package to match words and phrases to Entity labels',
    ext_modules = cythonize(ext)
)
```

Note the inclusion of gomp (aka libgomp.so.1). This is where GOMP_parallel is defined.

To compile do... `python setup.py build_ext`

I always used this code in-place (not installed anywhere) and to do that you need to set a link to the compiled entity_lookup.so that appears deep in the "build" directory that the script creates.